# How do JSON schema's anyOf type translate to typescript?

Tags: typescript, jsonschema

Let's say we have a schema like this (I borrowed the OpenAPI 3.0 format but I think the intention is clear):

```
{
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "HasName": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": { "type": "string" }
        }
      },
      "HasEmail": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "email": { "type": "string" }
        }
      },
      "OneOfSample": {
        "oneOf": [
          { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/HasName" },
          { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/HasEmail" }
        ]
      },
      "AllOfSample": {
        "allOf": [
          { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/HasName" },
          { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/HasEmail" }
        ]
      },
      "AnyOfSample": {
        "anyOf": [
          { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/HasName" },
          { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/HasEmail" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Based on this schema and the docs I read so far I would express types `OneOfSample` and `AllOfSample` like this:

```
type OneOfSample = HasName | HasEmail // Union type
type AllOfSample = HasName & HasEmail // Intersection type
```

But how would I express type `AnyOfSample`? Based on this page: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/ I would think of something like this:

```
type AnyOfSample = HasName | HasEmail | (HasName & HasEmail)
```

The question is **how do I correctly express the anyOf type in JSON schemas in typescript**?

Comment: I don't think you can accurately describe `anyOf` in TypeScript. Unions in TS aren't exact/exclusive, so even `HasName | HasEmail` is going to allow `{ name, email }` to be assigned to it. Maybe there's some magic with conditional types that would work, though... [read this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14094)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like "OneOf" means "must match *exactly* one", while "AnyOf" means "must match *at least* one".  It turns out that "at least one" is a more basic concept and corresponds to the [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) operation ("[inclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)") represented by the `|` symbol.  Therefore, the answer to your question as stated is just:

```
type AnyOfSample = HasName | HasEmail // Union type
```

A further union with the intersection doesn't change what values are accepted:

```
type AnyOfSample = HasName | HasEmail | (HasName & HasEmail)
```

because a union can only possibly add elements, and all of the elements of `HasName & HasEmail` are already present in `HasName | HasEmail`.  Observe:

```
type HasName = { name: string }
type HasEmail = { email: string };

type AnyOfIntersection = HasName | HasEmail | (HasName & HasEmail)
type AnyOfWithout = HasName | HasEmail

const aI: AnyOfIntersection = { name: "", email: "" }; // of course
const aW: AnyOfWithout = { name: "", email: "" }; // also accepted
```

You may want to keep the intersection if you are going to use [the `in` operator to narrow values](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing), which makes the technically-incorrect but often-useful assumption that if a key is *not known* to be present in a type, then it is *not* present:

```
function processAnyOf(aI: AnyOfIntersection, aW: AnyOfWithout) {
    if (("name" in aI) && ("email" in aI)) {
        aI; // (HasName & HasEmail)
    }
    if (("name" in aW) && ("email" in aW)) {
        aW; // never
    }
}
```

---

Of course this means you have an incorrect definition for `OneOfSample`.  This operation is more like a [disjunctive union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) (["exclusive or"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)), although not exactly because when you have three or more sets, the usual definition of a disjunctive union means "matches an odd number", which is not what you want.  As an aside, I can't find a widely used name for the type of disjunctive union we're talking about here, although here's an [interesting paper](http://www.sfu.ca/%7Ejeffpell/papers/IGPLTernaryExclOr.pdf) that discusses it.

So, how do we represent "matches exactly one" in TypeScript?  This isn't straightforward because it is most easily built in terms of the [negation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196) or [subtraction](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183) of types, which TypeScript can't currently do.  That is, you want to say something like:

```
type OneOfSample = (HasName | HasEmail) & Not<HasName & HasEmail>; // Not doesn't exist
```

but there is no `Not` that works here.  All you can do, therefore, is some kind of workaround... so what's possible?  You *can* tell TypeScript that a type may not have a particular property.  For example the type `NoFoo` may not have a `foo` key:

```
type ProhibitKeys<K extends keyof any> = {[P in K]?: never}; 
type NoFoo = ProhibitKeys<'foo'>; // becomes {foo?: never};
```

And you *can* take a list of key names and remove key names from another list (that is, subtraction of string literals), using conditional types:

```
type Subtract = Exclude<'a'|'b'|'c', 'c'|'d'>; // becomes 'a'|'b'
```

This lets you do something like the following:

```
type AllKeysOf<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never; // get all keys of a union
type ProhibitKeys<K extends keyof any> = {[P in K]?: never }; // from above
type ExactlyOneOf<T extends any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] & ProhibitKeys<Exclude<AllKeysOf<T[number]>, keyof T[K]>>;
}[number];
```

In this case, `ExactlyOneOf` expects a tuple of types, and will represent a union of each element of the tuple explicitly prohibiting keys from other types.  Let's see it in action:

```
type HasName = { name: string };
type HasEmail = { email: string };
type OneOfSample = ExactlyOneOf<[HasName, HasEmail]>;
```

If we inspect `OneOfSample` with IntelliSense, it is:

```
type OneOfSample = (HasEmail & ProhibitKeys<"name">) | (HasName & ProhibitKeys<"email">);
```

which is saying "either a `HasEmail` with no `name` property, or a `HasName` with no `email` property.  Does it work?

```
const okayName: OneOfSample = { name: "Rando" }; // okay
const okayEmail: OneOfSample = { email: "rando@example.com" }; // okay
const notOkay: OneOfSample = { name: "Rando", email: "rando@example.com" }; // error
```

Looks like it.

The tuple syntax lets you add three or more types:

```
type HasCoolSunglasses = { shades: true };
type AnotherOneOfSample = ExactlyOneOf<[HasName, HasEmail, HasCoolSunglasses]>;
```

This inspects as

```
type AnotherOneOfSample = (HasEmail & ProhibitKeys<"name" | "shades">) | 
  (HasName & ProhibitKeys<"email" | "shades">) | 
  (HasCoolSunglasses & ProhibitKeys<"email" | "name">)
```

which, as you see, correctly distributes the prohibited keys around.

---

There are other ways to do it, but that's how I'd proceed.  It is a workaround and not a perfect solution because there are situations it doesn't handle properly, such as two types with the same keys whose properties are different types:

```
declare class Animal { legs: number };
declare class Dog extends Animal { bark(): void };
declare class Cat extends Animal { meow(): void };
type HasPetCat = { pet: Cat };
type HasPetDog = { pet: Dog };
type HasOneOfPetCatOrDog = ExactlyOneOf<[HasPetCat, HasPetDog]>;
declare const abomination: Cat & Dog;
const oops: HasOneOfPetCatOrDog = { pet: abomination }; // not an error
```

In the above, `ExactlyOneOf<>` fails to recurse down into the properties of the `pet` property to make sure that it is not both a `Cat` and a `Dog`.  This can be addressed, but it starts getting more complicated than you probably want.  There are other edge cases too.  It depends on what you need.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwHJwLbQLxQN5QHZoQBcUCwATgJZ4DmUAvgFCiSyICiqclANlFrghdeJMlVoMA3I2bhoAQTwgA8gDMAymjA9MbZISgAfPZ258A9OaNQAFPH3ooAMhPCeAShksFStQEk8YAhyBAgAY2BKAHs8fj0UR2N7U15rO0QE6Bdkt09vKEUVVQB1SmAACyiAV2A4+0zrHLMZMJiyKDg-EkL-QODQiOjYgXxCEgAicYAaKCEzCfGpKEsoKNUoVqqQiEZWvHa4Yu7fErLKmrjcAnQFmbmRKEmllbgeBCiOsLCIMCCAExkqiqeEGMSgYHIUW+CAQPVUNk6xyKASC21BeBmhyRalKFWqwHcOEYUBJUEo6xsNnG1wgi2oHT8hKcLip9x4dNinXchOwxNJ-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-gBeEEdJxFBXgVSoMe5DuTMflQEFw6huGjD0D2yWpcEQ4PmZdoQA6Wg6J+KaWdZlXET2gboDMTS8O50jZqwTUaDVLodXwLhheuhF+tShDjKGhLGK6QZ5gW4UbtJE0ajN5V7O0UTNnAICZCQfWOs63Y0hMABKykxos96Hjte27G0tT3SAKQ8IdtnHbVIxshM5BXVEAACqYDQAdK0qA3chL2PfstR4L6yi7SAH1Vf1TrfTgow3I8l0NlE0yzG4f0A8D9UYxA4OnlDh7BJC5CZvk9gAMKLjwz60DwiChE2IwIOUcD-ggJAUFU0D3mZii+uUwRHQNdUNTZaN+i1GSEO1Ia8BrCCs1E7PAjQXMwnGXWZuYABU+RSxUsuffLWCim9oVLWNq2TegizGOM-OC3G02zeatiteKo0RVW6puJ7jw+0L-tGIH-Kirr+uc9zcbO6uy3jRHZhR+7tIzeb5iZv+P5wOQ0BlzCBR4JQXB8LgOg0ML+ApWl06l1zFcbEbTYACJRHQcmOTRih168WNFuXzY2O4JDGlElB-B34Rd5XvdQMzcDJnWI9NmP9dY+gUQAO6z-Pi-LxLTOILmXFb7UIyQMAJAP9ON8IHfwAD3QT9cSQP9345nsH1L+D9lDkEAVgCyERGq2RVvYMB29tZfx-qbTu5dK5PSMqeag28hiv23l6H+0gtrPSiGAFuIDbJIOABAqBWNn4kDgMZVAeDIhgluoaX0HZZjkHpkAA)

Comment: Great answer. I also would note that `HasName | HasEmail` is going to accept a *partial* object as long as *one* of the types is fully satisfied... I'm not sure that actually fits the precise `anyOf` requirement. But its as close as I guess you can get.

Comment: I massively misunderstood union types (`|`). I would have expected my `OneOfSample` to be correct.

Comment: I don't think that `HasName | HasEmail` and `HasName | HasEmail | (HasName & HasEmail)` is the same, see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwKIFs4EsA2UC8UDeAUFCVBGlgFxQLABO6AdgOaEC+hoksiAcnCmh4ipKIwERqtBi3aFCAMwCujAMbB0Ae0ZRECCHWABlek2YAKOHWZTTLAJQEOncNADyjCG4W4eyCtgAPn78gi7cAIKMIN6+8P4YQSESUMHxqIlQAGTJYYSq2rRQwBC0Hl4+wmy6CFDl3vmFwMWlwFExlU41UO0N8ug+5gBE4oJDUEwtZZ7ejiKkegbGdhYl0xUAdKMQ9uxkmPoExAsI+oYmMqut9Qob5Im7zgPD2+OTa23RsVk5Q-dYbx0H16CkcR1Ei3OK3MwK+t22uwhpyWFzMMNaILuAUeQA)

I think `HasName | HasEmail | (HasName & HasEmail)` is the correct for `anyOf`

Comment: I agree with @Gregor here `HasName | HasEmail` and `HasName | HasEmail | (HasName & HasEmail)` are definitely different

Comment: @Safareli Thanks for the feedback. I've edited the answer to hopefully address your concerns about the difference between `HasName | HasEmail` and `HasName | HasEmail | (HasName & HasEmail)`.  You won't find a value that is assignable to one that isn't also assignable to the other, so they describe the same set of values; but the compiler does allow some unsound narrowing based on key presence that treats them differently in some circumstances, so depending on usage you may indeed want the intersection in there.

Comment: That's actually something I have not thought about:
`const testOneOf: OneOf = { email: "", name: "" }`
compiles just fine

Comment: Very fun read, love it. Came to understand what `anyOf` meant with types because I didn't understand with words. Not disappointed at all

Answer (score 0):

The AnyOf compound is a bit of a weird one and hard to express in most languages. But, in TypeScript, we can create a type that does exactly what AnyOf does.

When using AnyOf, the types it contains need to validate at least once. When using it's sibling OneOf, then types need to validate exactly once. And when using AllOf all contained types need to validate.

If there is only one containing type, all three are the same

```
AllOf(A) = AnyOf(A) = OneOf(A) = A
```

AllOf and OneOf have a one to one relationship with TypeScript's intersection and union types. So

```
AllOf(A, B, C) = A & B & C
OneOf(A, B, C) = A | B | C
```

AnyOf is a little more complex, it needs to validate one or more contained types. Let's start with the 'one' part, this is the same as OneOf, so:

```
AnyOf(A, B, C) = A | B | C | ...
```

Now we also need to validate 'more' in this case more would be matching against two or three of the containing types. This would look like:

```
AnyOf(A, B, C) = A | B | C | (A & B) | (B & C) | (C & A) | (A & B & C)
```

So basically AnyOf is one of all possible combinations of the types is contains. You could use something like this
[Can you return n choose k combinations in Javascript using Array.flatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64414816/can-you-return-n-choose-k-combinations-in-javascript-using-array-flatmap/64414875#64414875) to figure out what this looks like exactly.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the idea of expressing a JSON Schema as a type definition is a paradigm mismatch. JSON Schema isn't designed for that kind of thing. It's trying to hammer a round peg into a square hole. It's never going to fit quite right.

JSON Schema is designed to translate into a function that can be used to validate a JSON document.

Comment: I got the same feeling too :D

Comment: This isn't an answer imo. You're right about JSON Schema being designed for runtime validation, but that validation function has to return something if it passes. How to type that object post-validation is a valid question and usecase for TypeScript.

Comment: @Gricey That validation function returns true or false. I'd do something like `function isMyType(n: unknown) => n is MyType`. How you define `MyType` has to do with the intended type the schema was intended to validate. The schema doesn't actually define that type, only validation constraints. You have to determine the type based on out-of-band information. The accepted answer is fantastic, but hopefully people can take a step back and see that all that type gymnastics is not what the author of the schema intended and do something more practical instead.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers exactly. And this question is about how the developer would create `MyType`, OP is asking for help representing *something* in typescript. There's nothing in the question that makes it invalid and your answer might be better as a comment since it doesn't answer the question as asked.

Comment: The question is not about defining a specific type. If it were, then I would agree with you. The question is specifically about the correct way to express `anyOf` in typescript. There is no correct answer. It depends on the context and the intent of the author.