# Non-disjunctive union of arbitrary number of types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In TypeScript, I'd like to create a union type representing values belonging to one *or more* different types, similar to `oneOf` in [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/#anyof) or [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#anyof). According to [a previous answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52838995/2432538), the union operator in TypeScript is supposed to do this, as it represents set union (inclusive or). However, that doesn't match with the type inference behavior in TypeScript when [using the in operator as a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator), which seems to assume that values belong to *exactly* one of the unioned types (disjunctive union or exclusive or). As a simple example, this [leads to a type error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsZgO5yhAEQgDcIAbdAB2mQG9kF0ATCACgEoAuZY9YJgNzIAvgFgAUKEixEKAMIALCDDoN06ANYduvfkLHiwAT2ppMOPIRLkq0APJRFy5AF4zWXPiKkK1KMgAfZCcYAQkJRhAAZzBkKPNPKx9bKABBECYQ11VGFm4OVwA+VWEAGjVNfPYikpEw8Qj0aNj4j0tvGz8HEO4MNq9rX3tHJRU3VosB5L90zNH64BVWACJciGXkUDiE9sGU7tHq2glkU+QAenPt-qTO4ayFOCjNkBhofCZkY1M+yduhqAnM4TRIdAEHZQAOjWHHqZwuVzkzFAAHNNs8FABXEAoqBGZDYdBQDRA06LZArRiaDZbEG7ab3Q50UnwhHIABy6FicDIFGwECY5SioCQ1z+YP2I2cj2eoDeUA+XxMKBA1kB4lZwJ2UzuUAhMGh6i07DhZwMBiAA):

```
interface SoftwareDeveloper { code(): void; }
interface Chef { cook(): void; }
type SoftwareDeveloperOrChef = SoftwareDeveloper | Chef;

// Determined at runtime. May have the code method, the cook method, or both.
const person = { code: () => { }, cook: () => { } };

const softwareDeveloperOrChef: SoftwareDeveloperOrChef = person;
if ("code" in softwareDeveloperOrChef) {
    // softwareDeveloperOrChef has inferred type SoftwareDeveloper
    softwareDeveloperOrChef.code();
    // Coding is hungry work
    if ("cook" in softwareDeveloperOrChef) {
        // Not allowed, since softwareDeveloperOrChef has inferred type never
        softwareDeveloperOrChef.cook();
    }
}
```

In order to get the behavior I want and [avoid type errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=13&ssc=80&pln=13&pc=75#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsZgO5yhAEQgDcIAbdAB2mQG9kF0ATCACgEoAuZY9YJgNzIAvgFgAUKEixEKAMIALCDDoN06ANYduvfkLHiwAT2ppMOPIRLkq0APJRFy5AF4zWXPiKkK1KMgAfZCcYAQkJRhAAZzBkKPNPKx9bKABBECYQ11VGFm4OVwA+VWEAGjVNfPYikpEw8QljUwwPS28bPwcQhwAhdDAFbJaLL2tfGiCsoNZhxPbx-wAyYKUYdnrImLiEtrGUrtXe-oVuWd3kzsdDqD6B7PjW0YvodMzV+uAVVgAiXIhv5CgbaPJIdexXZRHAbVWgSZDw5AAekRwJGoIWB2cCjgUUBIBg0HwTGQTRQZyeYP803J6JSyGWIXYcIRDzR832EJgUIUADo-hx6gjAV9fuoNACgay5ntLt0bscYcyhfDkchUmQKNgIExylFQEhUdLnlBMVz5XdsbjQASoESSSYyTsKQt6StlErlVLzpTTdy+WKBR6DAYgA), I have to manually add all combinations of intersection types to the union:

```
type SoftwareDeveloperOrChefOrBoth = SoftwareDeveloper | Chef | (SoftwareDeveloper & Chef);
const softwareDeveloperOrChefOrBoth: SoftwareDeveloperOrChefOrBoth = person;
if ("code" in softwareDeveloperOrChefOrBoth) {
    // softwareDeveloperOrChef has inferred type SoftwareDeveloper | (SoftwareDeveloper & Chef)
    softwareDeveloperOrChefOrBoth.code();
    if ("cook" in softwareDeveloperOrChefOrBoth) {
        // Allowed, since softwareDeveloperOrChefOrBoth has inferred type SoftwareDeveloper & Chef
        softwareDeveloperOrChefOrBoth.cook();
    }
}
```

An intermediate question could be if this is the behavior I should expect? However, given that it's the implemented behavior, I'm actually more interested in a way to construct the non-disjunctive union type for an arbitrary number of types. Doing it manually leads to an exponentially increasing size of the union type definition as the number of types increases:

```
type AorB = A | B | A & B;
type AorBorC = A | B | C | A & B | A & C | B & C | A & B & C;
type AOrBOrCorD = A | B | C | D | ... | B & C & D | A & B & C & D;
```

I can code generic types for specific number of parameters:

```
type AnyOf2<A, B> = A | B | A & B;
type AnyOf3<A, B, C> = AnyOf2<A, AnyOf2<B, C>>;
type AnyOf4<A, B, C, D> = ...;
```

But can I make a similar generic type that takes an arbitrary number of types, for example as a union (`AnyOf<A | B>`) using techniques like those used in the `UnionToIntersection` utility type [implemented here](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types/blob/ba66c895c7e52263268d179c142088f3e245a033/src/mapped-types.ts#L620-L633)?

Comment: From the example, it is not clear why you need the combination of all intersection types. To get rid of the TypeScript errors you can define an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) as `type SoftwareDeveloperOrChefOrBoth = SoftwareDeveloper & Chef;`

Comment: @mancristiana: The reason I can't use `SoftwareDeveloper & Chef` is because the value assigned to the variable is determined at runtime and may have not implement both interfaces. I've edited the question to add a comment that explains this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having errors is that using a union type doesn't properly allow for `SoftwareDeveloperOrChef` to be both `SoftwareDeveloper` and `Chef`.  If we know that the object is a `SoftwareDeveloper` then we have no information at all whatsoever about the `cook` property -- it could be anything.  It doesn't have to be a function of the expected type.

You're almost there with your `type AnyOf2<A, B> = A | B | A & B;`, but when we are dealing with properties on an object, we can make use of `Partial` and `Required`  to get a better type.

The final type that we are hoping to achieve for `SoftwareDeveloperOrChefOrBoth` is one where `cook` and `code` are both optional functions, but at least one is required.

Try this:

```
type EitherOrBoth<A, B> = Partial<A & B> & (A | B);

type SoftwareDeveloperOrChef = EitherOrBoth<SoftwareDeveloper, Chef>;
```

One change is that by using `Partial` you can no longer use `"code" in softwareDeveloperOrChef` as a type guard because the object could have the property key explicitly set to `undefined`.  For example `{code: undefined; cook: () => {};}` is a valid member of our type.

But this code checks out

```
const softwareDeveloperOrChef: SoftwareDeveloperOrChef = person;
if (softwareDeveloperOrChef.code) {
    softwareDeveloperOrChef.code();
    if (softwareDeveloperOrChef.cook) {
        // this is allowed now
        softwareDeveloperOrChef.cook();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Per our discussion in the comments, you want the individual interfaces `SoftwareDeveloper` and `Chef` have multiple methods and you want to be able to know for sure that if one method of `Chef` is present, that all of the other methods of `Chef` will also be present.

For maximum type safety, the combined `SoftwareDeveloperOrChefOrBoth` type should explicitly state that any members must either have all methods of `Chef` or none.

This utility type `Not<T>` handles this by saying that any keys of T cannot be set to anything other than `undefined`:

```
export type Not<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: never;
};
```

Note that simply not including the property doesn't say that it cannot be set. As explained in the [linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497299/typescript-prevent-assignment-of-object-with-more-properties-than-is-specified), with your `type AorB` you would get an error when creating a new invalid object (one which has all methods of `SoftwareDeveloper` and some but not all methods of `Chef`), but not when assigning the type to an existing object because this invalid object is assignable to `A` and therefore also assignable to `AorB`.

Instead of the looser `EitherOrBoth<A,B>` type suggested before, here is a stricter type which enforces exclusivity:

```
type ExclusiveAndOr<A, B> = A & Not<B> | B & Not<A> | A & B;

type SoftwareDeveloperOrChef = ExclusiveAndOr<SoftwareDeveloper, Chef>;
```

With this type, it is no longer just an assumption that if a person can `cook` they can also `chop`.

```
function checkPerson( softwareDeveloperOrChef: SoftwareDeveloperOrChef ) {
    if (softwareDeveloperOrChef.code) {
        softwareDeveloperOrChef.code();
        if (softwareDeveloperOrChef.cook) {
            // should be ok
            softwareDeveloperOrChef.cook();
            // ok to assume all methods exist
            softwareDeveloperOrChef.chop();
        } else {
            // should be error
            softwareDeveloperOrChef.chop();
        }
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcByEYB4AqA%20OAXjgG8AoOSuAbQAU4BLAOzgGthEIAzOHAXQD8ALjhNgAN2BQA3GQC%20sskhRwAoiADGAGwCuAZwaSAgkwAmAeShYjAGjgAhAsSNwAZOkxZHcAD4O3HthGBH4u7vaKzDBSXACGGqgAytwwAO6xUMAAIhLAWhAoUKRwFFQaEKbAABQAlCLiEAymslRwmXEaMNC19Y3N8mRkUTHxqADCABbAPCQlreUQrD1wDU0tZRMFy6v9coPKSSnpmTmS%20YWWk9NEapq6BsZmlljJXGkZ2bnnUnZXXHiKLg6JidBgQFgaKYaVi0KR6cFVODwt7HT5nApSS5TLgiV7vE5fDFQLHXGqkUqUBg8KrI-FovJEklcAB05UqZPIrVatNRpwZFygf1ZFWqNXWXMY1J5Hz532JguxwsWHIpEqoAHp1UjNjotKY4AAjVCLVVqpFHGWEgVChZLMWmtWauCLBAQOCxPR6HQAW1QsS0Wjgvpgm1MejgoAYehgDol0oJ6OtishW3tZrkEa0elQnLNGq1eh1esNqCkUGgsa58fpcqZrM2YFq4q5e1aez2ZHKTGjztYsqJuItCf5mIV12IucobOAIlqRAIJDkNlV7XiXSgs7JhAX7cGXZ7iz%20g5RlsTo7%20N0ncGnm-npCXK%20ma%20gt%20394GnfBB9Y9kwE2PdL9km47kq0zLgYsQE-Kq4HMoe2Ifvu8CmFG-r5KkwCmGMEDegaEAAbyVrntil4wRBfZEVAy7zBAiyvju8hAA)

Comment: Unfortunately, as you note, using `Partial` means that I lose the ability to use type guards. As an example, if I add `chop` to `Chef`, and I've checked that `softwareDeveloperOrChef.cook` exists, I can't rely on `chop` also being there. That makes the `AnyOf` solution work better for me.

Comment: You're potentially opening yourself up to errors if you assume that one function exists based on the presence of others. Keep in mind that a typescript interface doesn't say that you can have *only* those properties.  If I create an object `const person = { code: () => { }, cook: () => { } }`, this will be assignable to `AnyOf` because it is assignable to `SoftwareDevoloper`. But you can check that it includes `cook` and it does but it does not also include `chop`. So be careful that at runtime your object can only be a complete `Chef` or a complete `SoftwareDeveloper` and nothing in between.

Comment: Read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497299/typescript-prevent-assignment-of-object-with-more-properties-than-is-specified).  I'll edit my answer based on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for seeing potential sources of errors in my typings. However, my primary issue is still how to extend this "non-disjunctive union" to an arbitrary number of types without having to create individual `AnyOf2`/`ExclusiveAndOr2`, `AnyOf3`/`ExclusiveAndOr3`, ... types.