# Can you return n choose k combinations in Javascript using Array.flatMap?

Tags: javascript, arrays, probability

For instance, this is 5 choose 2:

```js
    var array = [0,1,2,3,4];
    
    var result = array.flatMap(
        (v, i) => array.slice(i+1).map(w => [v, w]) 
    );
    
    console.log(result);
```

How would I be able to do 5 choose 3 using this method?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 4], [0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]

Comment: @YuvalLevental  Rather than adding a comment for your expected result, edit your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add another level of nesting:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4];

var result = array.flatMap((v, i) =>
    array.slice(i+1).flatMap((w, j) =>
        array.slice(i+1+j+1).map(u =>
            [v, w, u]
        )
    )
);

console.log(result);
```

At this point, it might be easier to do with recursion though:

```js
function choose(arr, k, prefix=[]) {
    if (k == 0) return [prefix];
    return arr.flatMap((v, i) =>
        choose(arr.slice(i+1), k-1, [...prefix, v])
    );
}

console.log(choose([0,1,2,3,4], 3));
```

Comment: Anyway we can do the last one with strings too? As in pass it (["ab","cd","ef"],3) and get abcdef, cdabef, etc?

Comment: @mplungjan That example sounds like you're looking for permutations not combinations, but sure enough `choose` also works with string values (or really anything). Use `choose(["ab","cd","ef","gh"],3).map(c => c.join(''))`. You could build a string-specific version of `choose` as well that uses string concatenation instead of array consing.

Comment: Hi I [did find a permutation script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75410478/295783). Yours only does `[ "AABBCC"]` when given an array of AA,BB,CC

Comment: @mplungjan Well that's because the OP didn't ask for permutations here… There's lots of [SO threads about permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9960908/1048572), including [some with implementions of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1048572+permutations).